# Using mysql PDO with UPDATE command, but don't overwrite all values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am currently using a PHP framework which basically uses a wrapper for PDO, and am stumped on a problem. I have a page which takes any number of post variables, which could be any combination of the following:

```
":fullname" => $_POST['fullName'],
    ":universityID" => $_POST['university'], 
    ":gpa" => $_POST['gpa'], 
    ":major" => $_POST['major'], 
    ":gradYear" => $_POST['gradYear'], 
    ":photo" => "", 
    ":description" => $_POST['description'], 
    "howDidYouHear" => $_POST['howDidYouHear']
```

And I have an update statement which should look something like this:

```
$affectedRows = getDatabase()->execute('UPDATE user SET universityID = :universityID, 
gpa = :gpa, etc, WHERE fullName=:fullName', array(':universityID' =>     
$_POST['universityID'], ':gpa' => $_POST['gpa']));
```

Now the problem is if I do this sort of update statement I will be overwriting old data in the table, most of which is still valid. What I want to do is only update rows which I have new information for, and not touch the other ones. Is there a way to figure out within the query which ones should and should not be changed?

Comment: try to `var_dump($_POST);` and see what's in it

Comment: You wrote "only update rows which I have new information for". Don't you mean columns, not rows?

Comment: @Barmar, my apologies, you are correct, I did mean columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sets = array();
$vals = array();

for ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  if ($value == '') { continue; }
  switch ($key) {
  case "university":
    $sets[] = 'universityID = ?';
    $vals[] = $value;
    break;
  case "gpa":
  case "major":
  case "gradYear":
  case "description":
  case "howDidYouHear":
    $sets = "$key = ?";
    $vals = $value;
    break;
  }

$sql = 'UPDATE user SET ' . implode(', ', $sets) . 'WHERE fullname = ?';
$vals[] = $_POST['fullname'];
$affectedRows = getDatabase()->execute($sql, $vals);
```

Comment: It took me a minute of reading this solution to figure out how it worked exactly, but now that I see I like it! I will definitely have to try this out.

Comment: I ended up using your solution with a few modifications to solve my problem, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that if you pass an empty value in a certain field, you want it to retain the original value. use `if` in your `UPDATE` clause, example

```
UPDATE user 
SET universityID = IF(:universityID = '', universityID, :universityID),
    gpa = IF(:gpa = '', gpa, :gpa), ....
```

or something like that

Comment: I was originally considering this, I was just struggling finding how exactly I could implement if statements to work in this, thank you for the example, it helps considerably!

Comment: Even though I didn't use this solution, I am glad to see now exactly how I can use IFs in a query, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make a select query to get the current data, compare to your post data, and update only the changes.

Comment: Understood, thats what I was trying to do, I was just having trouble executing it in practice, I got it now though :)

Answer (score 0):

Add more conditions to your `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT
 ...
WHERE fullName=:fullName
  AND thisRowIsNew=1
```

Comment: I only needed to select 1 row based on userID to update though, sorry if I'm understanding what you mean but I don't think this would of worked.

Comment: It would have if it was the question you were actually asking.